# Change keyboard color for UISearchBar

Tags: ios, colors, keyboard, xcode5

I would really like to change the color of the "Search" button on the keyboard to match the theme of my app. But if that is not possible, at least I would like to do

```
self.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
```

But that does not work because, as I guess, the searchBar is not a UITextField. So how might I do this successful? I mean, change the color of the "Search" on the keyboard: whether fully or just the dark theme.

Answer (score 15):

For iOS 8 use

`self.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark`

Answer (score 5):

Try this, it works with IOS 6 , IOS 7 and IOS 8:

```
[self setKeyboardOnSearchBar:self.searchBar];
```

And the function:

```
-(void)setKeyboardOnSearchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    for(UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews) {
        if([subView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
            [(UITextField *)subView setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
            [(UITextField *)subView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeySearch];
        } else {
            for(UIView *subSubView in [subView subviews]) {
                if([subSubView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
                    [(UITextField *)subSubView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeySearch];
                    [(UITextField *)subSubView setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
for(UIView *subView in self.searchBar.subviews) {
        if([subView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
            [(UITextField *)subView setKeyboardAppearance: UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 update, iOS 11+ :

```
    searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .dark
    searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .light
    searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .default
```

Comment: Now (swift 4) `.alert` is deprecated and equal to `.dark`

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5, iOS 14:

If Search bar is present inside a specific view (eg- SearchBarView),

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [SearchBarView.self]).keyboardAppearance = .dark
```

Will cause change only for the specific search bar inside the SearchBarView.

Else if you want to do for all Search Bars then,

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).keyboardAppearance = .dark
```